# Triple LinearLayout with weightSUM

Tags: java, android, xml

I have 3 LinearLayout in 1 LinearLayout like in screen:

[image]

Like you see, last layout should be bigger than 1st and this same like 2nd.
BUT, look like this look:

[image]

Definitely, last layout is like 80% of the screen ! What is going on ?
How to fix it ? I want 20 % 40 % and 40%

My xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/e1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/e2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:rowCount="2"
        android:weightSum="2">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:text="SavetoDB" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:text="LoadFromDB" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:text="Clear Database" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/l1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I waste whole day for this layout and it still does not work ...

Comment: updated the answer ..update if it works..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change all of your `linearLayouts` height **(except the topmost)** to `android:layout_height="0dp"` it will work :)

Comment: works, thanks ! I will accept your answet, but I need wait 5 min

Comment: lel ..then do it after 5 mins :)

Answer (score 2):

I modified your xml. Please have a look

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/e1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/e2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".4"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:rowCount="2">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:text="SavetoDB" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:text="LoadFromDB" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:text="Clear Database" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".4"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/l1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

replace all of your linearLayout height  to "0dp"